# Fullcalendar different maxtime for different days in angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am implementing the different maxtime for different days using the fullcalendar plugin, but not able to achieve it. Below is my code

```
<full-calendar #calendar defaultView="timeGridWeek" [defaultDate]="TODAY" [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
        [events]="events" [editable]="true" [firstDay]="1" slotDuration="00:30:00" slotLabelInterval="00:30:00"
        minTime="09:00:00" maxTime="18:30:00" eventResizableFromStart="true" [eventStartEditable]="true"
        [resizable]="true" (eventResize)="handleEventResize($event)" [nowIndicator]="false" height="auto"
        header="{left: '', center: '', right: ''}" [allDaySlot]="false" aspectRatio="3" [eventOverlap]="false"
        (eventRender)="handleEventRender($event)" defaultTimedEventDuration="00:30" (dateClick)="dateClick($event)"
        (datesRender)="datesRender($event)" [slotLabelFormat]="{
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        omitZeroMinute: false,
        meridiem: 'short'
      }" [eventTimeFormat]="{
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: 'short'
      }" (eventDrop)="eventDrop($event)">
    </full-calendar>
```

I want to have maxtime for Saturday as 16:30 and for Sunday as 14:30.

Please note that I have to use this plugin only and it is not a paid plugin. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `I want to have maxtime for Saturday as 16:30 and for Sunday as 14:30`..this isn't possible with fullCalendar currently unfortunately. Maybe you can make a feature request - https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the update. Will make a feature request for the same.